# Cannot change Connected App Permitted Users

Tags: connected-apps

When I log into Salesforce, I cannot change Permitted Users on this connected app. If I go to a different sandbox (where I have created a similar app) I CAN change this. I am the creator of both connected apps and I have system administrator permissions in both sandboxes. All other settings, as far as I can tell and remember, are the same.

Why would this option be locked?

[image]

Comment: Is there a package that installed the connected app as a managed package ?Only manage package can lock it .

Comment: No, I JUST created this in the environment where I am trying to change it. That is why it is so perplexing.

Comment: What is the navigation path you have reached the page ? Via Admin or via Develop > Apps . Please try both the navigational paths

Comment: I have tried both paths and it results in the same restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I navigated to Manage Apps -> Connected Apps and edited the options at the top of the page: "Limit API access to installed connected apps with the "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" policy" was checked.

Comment: This path doesn't seem to exist in the current UI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a new iteration of this issue in 2023, but my behavior was that I could edit the field, but on save it was reverted.

I fixed this by removing my Client Credentials "Run As" user and saving. Then I was able to change the settings for Permitted Users and save. Then finally re-added the "Run As" user.

Comment: Possibly this is also the fix for @k3davis

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too.  I was able to change these details in sandboxes but not in production; but this is a current successful workaround